# Are women superior or inferior to men?

Tags: women

There are contradictory opinions regarding whether women are spritually inferior to men or superior.
Some verses tell us that women are inferior while others tell us that women are superior.

Eg - **Verses that indicates women are inferior.**

Gita 9:42

> By taking refuge in Me even those of sinful birth, **women**, vaiśyas and also śūdras attain the supreme state

Vidur [says](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m05/m05039.htm) to Dhritarastra:

> One should not place trust on a **woman**, a swindler, an idle person, a coward, one that is fierce, one that boasts of his own power, a thief, an ungrateful person, and an atheist.

In [this](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/48253/23709) answer there are many verses that denigrate women. You can read it .

**Verses which glorify women** -

All women are the form of Goddess Laxmi. (common Hindu belief)

Adi Parva, Mahabharata Book, 1.74.50-51

> No man, even in anger, should ever do anything that is disagreeable to his wife; for happiness, joy, virtue and everything depend on the wife. Wife is the sacred soil in which the husband is born again, even the Rishis cannot create men without women

So, what is the final opinion whether women are spiritually superior or inferior to men ?

Comment: Shiva-Shakthi combine principle emphasizes equality and complementary nature of both theses constitutive forms. But full equality was not developed, the inferior position of women prevailed even in ancient history.